# Using ring R=$\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^n+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography

Currently studying Ring-LWE,[here](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/lattice-survey.pdf#page=24), and having trouble grasping a concrete definition of what this means, as a ring. My understanding is that everything in this ring is an integer polynomial, and that it must be reduced $X^n+1$, is this correct? Essentially working modulo $X^n+1$.

It then goes on to work in quotient group $R_q=R/qR$. When in this quotient group, would all elements have already been reduced $X^n+1$ and finally then reduced mod $q$?

Comment: For your first question,, it's exactly that. In practice, when you muktiply two congruence classes, each time you meet  $X^nˆ$, you replace it with $-1$, $X^{n+1}$ is replaced with $-X$, and so on. For your second question, $q$ is (the congruence class of) another polynomial?

Comment: Nb: the ring depends on what $n$ is; if $n = 3$, for example, then $X^3 + 1$ is reducible so you end up with a product of rings.

Comment: In the paper $q$ is assumed to be an '*integer modulus*', and more general rings are considered. But yes, $R/qR$ just takes the residues when divided by $q$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polynomials are just multiplied as usual but any term $X^N$ is replaced by $-1$, $X^{n+1} \equiv -X$ etc. , as we consider $X^n+1$ to be equivalent to $0$.

All coefficients of those polynomials lie in $\mathbb{Z}_q$, so whenever they go above $q$, reduce them.

So a simple example: $n=3$, $q=3$, then $$(1+X+X^2)(1+2X+2X^2)= 1 + 2X + 2X^2 + X + 2X^2 + 2X^3 + X^2 + 2X^3 + 2X^4=1 + 3X + 5X^2 +4X^3 + 2X^4 \equiv 1+ 2X^2 + 4(-1) + 2(-X) \equiv (1-4) - 2X +2X^2 \equiv X +2X^2$$

for example (modulo calculation errors, working from screen)

Comment: So both reductions can be done simultaneously? In this instance, $n$ is a power of two. So if I were to use an example based on a Ring-LWE instance:
"Choosing $a\in R_q"$. I will set $q=5,n=2^2=4$. Thus giving the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^4+1)$ and the quotient ring $R_q=R_{5}=R/5R$ (sorry if formatting is confusing).

If $a$ is initially sampled as (1,5,2,8,11) this would give:
\begin{equation}
1+5X+2X^2+8X^3+11X^4=1+2X^2+3X^3+(1)*(-1)=2X^2+3X^3 
\end{equation}
Thus $a\in R_q$. Obviously both $q$ and $n$ would be much bigger, but just wondering if the reduction has been done correctly.

Comment: @Stilton indeed the order of reductions is irrelevant. I’ll check the example later.

Comment: @Stilton you’re sampling in a different space? You have to pick a vector of length $n$ which codes an element of the ring (maximal degree $n-1$), as an error element.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake.  Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, working in $\Bbb Z[X]/(X^n+1)$ means working with integer polynomials modulo $X^n+1$.

As for the second question, yes, $R/qR$ means reducing first modulo $X^n+1$, then modulo $q$. However, by the third isomorphism theorem, this is essentially the same as first reducing modulo $q$, then reducing modulo $X^n+1$. Assuming $q$ is an integer, that way is usually easier to work with.

Comment: Yes the coefficients are in $\Bbb Z_q$ most of the time.